# Is it possible to reference other var in `transform`?

Tags: r

Is it possible to reference other var in `transform`?

For instance:

```
Data = transform(Data, 
              m = x,
              d = m,
              c = m * 2
)
```

Comment: What is `Data`, `x`, etc. here? A short answer is: no, you cannot reference `m` in `transform`

Comment: Why won't you just test your code on a sample data and get your answer?

Comment: to David Arenburg, I did, and I couldn't figure out how to make it work. 

Thanks @gagolews, that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some solutions. For reproducibility we will assume this definition for `Data`:

```
Data <- data.frame(x = 1)
```

**1) iterated transform** Try an iterated transform:

```
transform(transform(Data, m = x), d = m, c = m*2)
```

**2) within** or use `within`:

```
within(Data, { m <- x; d <- m; c <- m*2 })
```

**3) my.transform** There is also an alternate transform defined [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/139952.html) that supports such behavior.

```
my.transform(Data, m = x, d = m, c = m*2)
```

Note that this is the only answer here that supports setting the variables out of order, e.g.

```
my.transform(Data, d = m, c = m*2, m = x)
```

**4) dplyr::mutate**  `mutate` in the dplyr package also supports this:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(Data, m = x, d = m, c = m*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, *if you mean a variable you create in the **current** `transform()` call*:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
df2 <- transform(df, m = x, d = m, c = m * 2)

> df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
> df2 <- transform(df, m = x, d = m, c = m * 2)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'm' not found
```

The obvious solution is to do two `transform()` calls:

```
df2 <- transform(df, m = x)
df2 <- transform(df2, d = m, c = m * 2)
head(df2)

> head(df2)
  x m d  c
1 1 1 1  2
2 2 2 2  4
3 3 3 3  6
4 4 4 4  8
5 5 5 5 10
6 6 6 6 12
```

or nest them

```
df3 <- transform(transform(df, m = x), d = m, c = m * 2)

> head(df3)
  x m d  c
1 1 1 1  2
2 2 2 2  4
3 3 3 3  6
4 4 4 4  8
5 5 5 5 10
6 6 6 6 12
```

The alternative is `within()`, which can do what you want but is slightly less user-friendly:

```
df4 <- within(df, {
    m <- x
    d <- m
    c <- m * 2
  })

> head(df4)
  x  c d m
1 1  2 1 1
2 2  4 2 2
3 3  6 3 3
4 4  8 4 4
5 5 10 5 5
6 6 12 6 6
```

One idiosyncrasy of this is that you don't have any control of the ordering of the new variables.

Note that `within()` works because the entire expression (the thing in `{ ... }`) is evaluated within an environment containing the variables in `df`. Hence `m` is available in that environment as it is created in the first line of the expression.